# Using .htaccess, how can I append a GET variable on redirect based on current GET variables?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm using `.htaccess` to redirect website admin pages to a global admin page, and what I'd like to do is append the referring website to the end of the URL, which may contain a query string already. I have no clue where to start, and haven't found anything with the right information, yet.

What I'd like to do is redirect URL's in the following manner:

```
site2.com/admin/        => site1.com/admin/?ref=site2
site3.com/admin/?page=1 => site1.com/admin/?page=1&ref=site3
```

Is anyone aware of a way that I can append `ref=site#` to the URL, and use the proper character based on whether the URL has a query already?

Thank you in advance to any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)ref=site1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?ref=site1 [R=302,L,QSA,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/$ http://site1.com/admin/?ref=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out how to do this with some more searching, which led me right to the [Httpd Wiki Rewrite Query String](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString) page for the answer. How did I miss that? I appreciate the answers I received, but none of them did exactly what I was looking for. The answer is extremely simple, also. For anyone else interested:

```
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$    http://ADMIN_SITE/admin$1?ref=REF_SITE    [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

The QSA flag will automatically add the query string after the `?ref` query.